# Setting joint velocity through plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm writing a model plugin in C++ to use with ROS+Gazebo via python (similar to AtlasPlugin)
I wrote a reset function to allow me to set initial conditions for a model (world position, joints positions and velocities). Everything is working right except for the joint velocities.
I'm using Joint::SetVelocity() but nothing happens. I also tried using Joint::Update() after and still nothing...
Here's a small snippet of my code:

```
this->joints[i]->SetVelocity(0,_req.joint_vel[i]);
this->joints[i]->Update();
```

I'll appreciate any help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2743/setting-joint-velocity-through-plugin/) by [Lothas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/176/lothas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-05-10**:
If possible, you could use SetForce instead of SetVelocity as I think that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should call SetMaxForce for the joint. This tells the physics engine the maximum force that can be applied to a joint in order to achieve the specified velocity.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What does `this->joints[i]->GetMaxForce(0)` return?. I stumbled into this recently, and figured that the MaxForce needs to be set to a nonzero value, ie.

```
this->joints[i]->SetMaxForce(0, nonzero_val)
```

The odd thing was that I could do `this->joints[i]->SetAngle(0, angle)` with the MaxForce set to zero and it worked. AFAICT the joint was not static.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) with karma: 275 on 2013-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2